# Is it possible to copy video files to the XBOX 360 hard drive with the latest dashboard improvements?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive, xbox-dashboard

With the advent of the 250Gb XBO 360 and the latest dashboard improvements it seems that movie files (such as .avi, .wmv, etc.) still can't be copied to the console's hard drive from an external drive, is there a way to achieve this?

I recently bought one of the new, revised XBOX 360s under the impression that it could also be used as a kind of media hub and so I wouldn't have to play content from an external hard drive or by streaming from another computer. What is the purpose of the large hard drive if users are heavily restricted in what they can use it for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't copy videos to the hard drive.

The larger hard drive is meant for all sorts of things like downloaded content and videos from the marketplace, game demos, XBLA games, DLC, full installed games, etc.

Comment: The best you can do is stream it from a computer or put the media on a USB memory stick.